# How to combine ls and cd commands in Unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix

`ls`, gives me all directories

`ls -trh`, gives me all directories sorted by date (newest last)

`ls -dtrh */ | tail -1`, gives me name of latest directory (by date)

Is it possible to somehow incorporate the `ls` and `cd` commands, so I could navigate to the latest directory. Something logically equal to `ls -trh | tail -1 | cd`, but working.

Comment: It also gives you files.  You can't cd to a file.

Comment: Migrate this question to Super User?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
cd "$(ls -trh | tail -1)"
```

This uses the output of the the ls|tail pipeline as the command-line arguments to cd.

EDIT: camh is correct that this should give better performance, because `head` won't go through the lines you're ignoring.

```
cd "$(ls -th | head -1)"
```

Comment: I'd suggest instead of reverse sorting and using tail, you use a normal sort and use head. That way it processes less data: `cd $(ls -th | head -n 1)` (I know the OP used -r|tail, but we can improve on that)

Comment: @camh, good suggestion.

Comment: Protect the command substitution with double quotes, or else it won't work when the directory contains spaces.

Answer (score 2):

solution using backticks:

```
cd `ls -th | head -1`
```

Answer (score 2):

I have done an alias for my own use:

`alias cdu='cd $(ls -rtd */ | tail -1)'`

this will put you in last modified/created directory in your position.

Answer (score 1):

Use this simple command:

```
cd `ls -t`
```

The character <`> is a backtick character. Not an apostrophe.

This will go to the latest directory. Try it.

Comment: It will probably not, and is more likely to return a "too many arguments" error. I say probably, because it will work if a single directory is in the current-dir.